# Angularjs 1.x and Typescript and post value to server

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I am trying to post header values to the server but values not embedded in **request header** thats why its give me wrong answer. I know, I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out it. Below is my code.

```
 checkMobileNo (mob: any): ng.IPromise<ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>>{
  var config: ng.IRequestShortcutConfig = {
    headers: {
      MobileNo : mob,
      DeviceFlag : 'WebOS'
    }
  };
  return this.$http.post("http://abcd.com/api/DemoWebAPI/IsValidMobileNo", config)
}
```

I already add reference path into that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [post method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) signature is

```
post(url, data, [config])
```

And you're using

```
post(url, config)
```

So the config object you're passing is in fact sent as the body/data of the request.

Comment: Then on which parameter should i pass the header value data or config? Because I pass data values is {} then also gives me same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem using this line

```
  return this.$http.post("http://abcd.com/api/DemoWebAPI/IsValidMobileNo", {}, config)
```